# Bad Performance of PL/SQL function vs build-in sysdate in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timezone, sysdate

I have an *oracle* database, which is setup with timezone 'Europe/Berlin' and the data is stored in 'UTC'. In that environment *sysdate* will deliver current time in Berlin, that is why it cannot be used in queries, because it would compare dates of different time zones.

```
select * from table 
where time_col < sysdate --bad comparision
```

so in order to compare with the current time in the correct timezone I would need to change to

```
select * from table 
where time_col < cast(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as date)
```

or using sys_extract_utc()

```
select * from table
where time_col < sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)
```

in order to make the timezone configurable, I added a parameters table, to retrieve the timezone from, making the query look like

```
select * from table 
where time_col < (select cast(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE nvl(parameter_value, 'UTC') as date)  
    FROM parameter_table 
    where parameter_name = 'DBTimeZone')
```

or joining the parameters tables

```
select * from table, parameter_table 
where time_col < cast(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE nvl(parameter_value, 'UTC') as date) 
and parameter_name = 'DBTimeZone'
```

in order to avoid making queries unreadable I added a *pl/sql package* to implement my own sysdate function like this

```
create or replace package time_pkg as
  function sysdateDB return date;
end;
/
create or replace package body time_pkg as
  dbtz VARCHAR2(100) := 'UTC';
  function sysdateDB return date
  as
  begin
   return sysdate at time zone dbtz;
  end;
  begin
   dbtz := util.GetParameter('DBTimeZone', dbtz);
  end;
/
```

so in any query I can use *time_pkg.sysdateDB* instead of *sysdate* to compare data in the database with the current time of the same timezone.

```
select * from table where time_col < time_pkg.sysdateDB
```

However with some very complex queries there is a huge performance difference.

- *sysdate* needs just 1 second
- *sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)* needs just 1 second
- *systimestamp at time zone 'UTC'* needs 2 seconds
- *time_pkg.sysdateDB* needs 50 seconds
- *time_pkg.sysdate* (not in above listing, just returns sysdate) also needs 20 seconds.

So the performance of build-in *sysdate* is always better than calling a function which just returns *sysdate*

Any ideas how to either improve the performance of the *pl/sql* function or any alternative writting to get the current time at a configurable timezone

**Disclaimer**: there is probably a performance difference in every query, but if the query still returns below 100ms nobody notices a problem.

Maybe the problem is the choice of the columns in the database, instead of timestamp with timezone we use date. Not sure if timestamp with timezone would correclty compare to sysdate (without timezone). Anyway changing the complete datamodel is not an option currently.

Comment: How much are the function timings affected if you add [PRAGMA UDF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/UDF-pragma.html) to them? I believe that tries to minimise the impact of context switching, which is probably at least part of your issue. (And as for "Not sure if timestamp with timezone would correclty compare to sysdate" - no, but it would against `systimestamp`.)

Comment: @AlexPoole I was exactly looking for something like this. However it brings 0 improvement. Not sure if you understand german, but this [article on Pragma UDF](https://www.robotron.de/unternehmen/aktuelles/blog/neue-pl/sql-features-ii-pragma-udf), says there is usually no impact on date functions

Comment: How many rows you have in the table? with the pl/sql function, you're doing sql to pl/sql switch for each row, while when you use sysdate it is executed just once for the whole query

Comment: No (or not for a long time!), but [this](https://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/pragma-udf-some-current-limitations/) says the same. It's quite old though, so I'd hoped it had improved - but it seems not in my 19c DB. That's a shame...

Comment: @gsalem yes, you are right, that is what I found also. there are 2.1 Million records in that table.

Answer (score 3):

Making the function deterministic as you did is not a good solution. As it is, if you run your query twice, the function will be called just one time, and so it will not return the proper sysdate, instead it will return the sysdate of it's first run. To solve this issue, add a varying parameter to it, like this:

```
create or replace package time_pkg as
  function sysdateDB (sd date)return date deterministic;
  function sysdateDBnd (sd date)return date ;
end;
/
create or replace package body time_pkg as
  dbtz VARCHAR2(100) := 'UTC';
  function sysdateDB (sd date)return date deterministic
  as
  begin
   return sysdate at time zone dbtz;
  end;
  function sysdateDBnd (sd date)return date 
  as
  begin
   return sysdate at time zone dbtz;
  end;
  begin
   dbtz := 'UTC';
  end;
/
```

I used 2 function to let you easily see the difference (and I don't have you util package, so I just fixed the dbtz variable).

```
select max(time_pkg.sysdateDB(sysdate))
from dual
connect by level<10000000;
MAX(TIME_PKG.SYSDAT
-------------------
03/01/2023 16:50:30

Elapsed: 00:00:02.404

select max(time_pkg.sysdateDBnd(sysdate))
from dual
connect by level<10000000;
MAX(TIME_PKG.SYSDAT
-------------------
03/01/2023 16:51:15

Elapsed: 00:00:42.779
```

Comment: If you're going to do that wouldn't it make sense to use `sd` inside the function instead of `sysdate`? (And maybe make the argument a timestamp with timezone and pass in systimestamp, to avoid the implicit conversion. I'd personally also cast the result to date for clarity, but not vital...)

Comment: Why not Alex, though it would not impact performance that much, as it is called just once for all the query (2.1 rows).

Comment: thank you for pointing out, but currently i cannot imagine, where i would need sysdate to change during one query execution. Best case would be query execution time = 0, sysdateDB should not be expected to change. If i run your testcase with just sysdate, the result is the same as with the deterministic function. that is exactly what I wanted to achieve. A function with performs and behaves like sysdate

Comment: @tejoe: The `DETERMINISTIC` keyword tells the DBMS that for the same parameters the function will always return the same result. The function you posted in your answer evaluates different results when we run it now and ten minutes later again, but the keyword says that both calls will return the same value. This means that Oracle could take the liberty not to call the function, but just cache the result. Then you'd get a wrong result at a later call.

Comment: @tejoe: So, you may have misunderstood what gsalem tells you in this answer. This is not about running the function more then once in the same query. It is about running it now and then at some other time again. Your function is dangerous because by tricking the DBMS into believing that every call will return the same value, you may get an unexpected result (i.e. an old datetime). gsalem's solution with a date parameter on the other hand rightly promises that each call with the same sysdate is deterministic for the session. It doesn't make false promises and can hence be run without risk.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: i double checked the method. when i call the function after 1 second i get the new result. Also if i use it in a plsql block twice, i get different results for each explicit call. However you are right. Oracle may change its behaviour and add caching. So like gsalem showed in his example i will use a 'function sysdateDB (sd date)return date deterministic', that should update everytime oracle considers sysdate being updated

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to to comment of @gsalem I did a lookup on how to make a function "stable". Adding the keyword *deterministic* seems to do the job and almost reaches the performance of build-in oracle *sysdate*

```
create or replace package time_pkg as
  function sysdateDB return date deterministic;
end;
/
create or replace package body time_pkg as
  dbtz VARCHAR2(100) := 'UTC';
  function sysdateDB return date deterministic
  as
  begin
   return sysdate at time zone dbtz;
  end;
  begin
   dbtz := util.GetParameter('DBTimeZone', dbtz);
  end;
/
```

Comment: I downvoted, because it is a bad idea to lie to the DBMS and make it belive that the function will always return the same value. It doesn't. If the DBMS relies on the promise and caches the result in order to return it at a later call, you'll get undesired results - and rightfully so.